# How to sort list alphabetically which includes HTML Tags

Tags: ios, sorting, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

how can i sort my list alphabetically with NSFetchedResultsController, when the text contains HTML tags.

For example, i have to sort this:

```
- <b>Hello</b>
- Adam
```

The Result should be:

```
- Adam
- <b>Hello</b>
```

This is how i sort it at the moment:

```
sortString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"title"];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortString ascending:sortAsc selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, sortDescriptor2, nil] autorelease];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

So, is there a way to sort "splitted"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way: construct a specialized NSSortDescriptor with your own selector. Since NSString has standard method to do what you want, you will need to create a category on NSString named something like "compareWithHTML:", which strips the HTML and does the comparison using "compare:" or "localizedCompare:.